# How to get datatable from stored procedure?

Tags: c#-4.0, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have a below stored procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE "SP_UTILITIES_LOG"
(
p_utility_name IN varchar2,
p_r_object_id IN varchar2,
p_platform_name IN varchar2,
p_exported_file_path IN varchar2,
p_Is_binary IN number,
p_extraction_status IN varchar2,
p_extraction_error IN varchar2,
p_extraction_datetime IN VARCHAR2,
p_schema_name IN varchar,
p_publication_path IN varchar,
p_schema_tcm_id IN varchar,
p_component_tcm_id IN varchar,
p_component_name IN varchar,
p_loading_status IN varchar,
p_transformed_file_path IN varchar,
p_transformed_status IN varchar,
p_import_status IN varchar,
p_loading_error IN varchar,
p_transform_error IN varchar,
p_import_error IN varchar,
p_loading_datetime IN TIMESTAMP,
p_transform_datetime IN TIMESTAMP,
p_import_datetime IN TIMESTAMP

)
   IS  
   BEGIN

    IF(p_utility_name ='EXTRACTION')
    THEN
    BEGIN
   INSERT INTO utilities_log(R_OBJECT_ID,
PLATFORM_NAME,
EXPORTED_FILE_PATH,
IS_BINARY,
EXTRACTION_STATUS,
EXTRACTION_ERROR,
EXTRACTION_DATETIME
)
   VALUES(p_r_object_id, p_platform_name,p_exported_file_path, p_is_binary, p_extraction_status, p_extraction_error, p_extraction_datetime); 

    END;
    END IF;


    IF(p_utility_name ='LOADING')
    THEN
    BEGIN

    UPDATE UTILITIES_LOG SET schema_name=p_schema_name,
    publication_path= p_publication_path,
    schema_tcm_id= p_schema_tcm_id,
    component_tcm_id= p_component_tcm_id,
    component_name= p_component_name,
    loading_status= p_loading_status,
    loading_error= p_loading_error,
    loading_datetime= current_timestamp
    WHERE
    r_object_id= p_r_object_id;

    END;
    END IF;


    IF(p_utility_name ='PRE-TRANSFORMATION')
    THEN
    BEGIN
    SELECT exported_file_path,component_tcm_id FROM utilities_log
    WHERE
    platform_name= p_platform_name and loading_status=p_loading_status
    and extraction_status=p_extraction_status;


    END;
    END IF;


    IF(p_utility_name ='TRANSFORMATION')
    THEN
    BEGIN
    UPDATE UTILITIES_LOG SET 
    transformed_file_path= p_transformed_file_path,
    transformed_status= p_transformed_status,
    transform_error= p_transform_error,
    transform_datetime= current_timestamp
    WHERE
    exported_file_path= p_exported_file_path;

    END;
    END IF;

    IF(p_utility_name ='RETRIEVE')
    THEN
    BEGIN
    execute immediate 'create global temporary table temp_import as SELECT transformed_file_path,publication_path
    FROM utilities_log
    WHERE
    platform_name= p_platform_name';

    END;
    END IF;

    IF(p_utility_name ='IMPORTER')
    THEN
    BEGIN
    UPDATE UTILITIES_LOG SET 
    import_status=p_import_status,
    import_error=p_import_error,
    import_datetime=current_timestamp
    WHERE
    publication_path= p_publication_path;
    END;
    END IF;


   END;
```

I am getting error "Into" clause is missing in select statement...
Any help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is (returning a set of query results from an sp to c#), is by using the Ref Cursor type, provided by oracle.
You can see how its implemented [here](http://oradim.blogspot.co.il/2007/05/odpnet-tip-ref-cursors-and-fetchsize.html) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html)

**EDIT:**
It should look like this (i dont have oracle here, but you can easily check this):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "SP_UTILITIES_LOG" ( 
p_utility_name IN varchar2, 
p_r_object_id IN varchar2, 
/* your other parameters */
p_refcur out sys_refcursor /* notice the out parameter */
)
AS
BEGIN
/* one sample from your select*/
IF(p_utility_name ='PRE-TRANSFORMATION')
 THEN     
 BEGIN     
      OPERN p_refcur FOR 
      SELECT exported_file_path,component_tcm_id FROM utilities_log     
      WHERE     platform_name= p_platform_name 
     AND        loading_status=p_loading_status      
     AND extraction_status=p_extraction_status;       
 END;     
 END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: thanks Yavgeny for suggestion....I got through that... i never implemented that so its little bit difficult to understand at a fiirst glance....It will be of great help if you can modify the code....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(p_utility_name ='RETRIEVE') THEN
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'create global temporary table temp_import 
  as SELECT transformed_file_path,publication_path     
     INTO temp_import
     FROM utilities_log     
     WHERE platform_name= p_platform_name'
END     
END IF
```

I think

Comment: No; CTAS (`create table as select`) doesn't need the `into`. And temporary tables shouldn't be created on the fly in Oracle, but that's the OP's error, not yours *8-)

Comment: Damn didn't see the orackle tag.

Answer (score 1):

The error message relates to this:

```
IF(p_utility_name ='PRE-TRANSFORMATION')
THEN
BEGIN
SELECT exported_file_path,component_tcm_id FROM utilities_log
WHERE
platform_name= p_platform_name and loading_status=p_loading_status
and extraction_status=p_extraction_status;
END;
END IF;
```

In a PL/SQL block, the data has to be selected into something, so you'd need to declare some variables, and then do:

```
SELECT exported_file_path,component_tcm_id
INTO <local_exported_file_path_var>, <local_component_tcm_id_var>
FROM utilities_log
...
```

You could then use those variables elsewhere in the SP, which you don't seem to have a need for at the moment, so not sure why you're selecting at all. Or have `OUT` parameters you could select them into so they could be accessed by the caller, but you aren't doing that either.

Temporary tables shouldn't be created on the fly in Oracle, so the whole concept seems confused. If you're trying to return a table of data to the caller, then as @YavgenyP says, look at ref cursors. Not sure quite what you are trying to do though.